# Creating empty array of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, arrays

following some tutorial, and came across this code:

.h

```
class Swarm {
public:
    const static int NPARTICLES = 5000;
private:
    Particle * m_pParticles;
public:
    Swarm();
};
```

.cpp

```
Swarm::Swarm() {
    m_pParticles = new Particle[NPARTICLES];
}
```

I can't understand how, when i declare a variable of type Particle `Particle * m_pParticles;` it becomes an array of pointers to `Particle` in the constructor. Because iirc an array should be initialized like `MyObject *pObjects[N] = {}`. Please help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: It's a dynamically-allocated array of `Particle`s, not `Particle` pointers. You can point a `Particle` pointer to the start of that array. However, the right tool here is `std::vector<Particle>`.

Comment: See [tutorial on pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) especially the section `Pointers and arrays`. `new Particle[NPARTICLES]` returns the pointer to some heap allocated array. Beware: This class as is is a memory leak, as there is no destructor freeing the memory.

Comment: As an alternative to `std::vector`, since `NPARTICLES` is a compile time constant you could use `std::array<Particle, NPARTICLES>`

Comment: @Krom I have intentionally removed descrtuctor for clean example. In original code its present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a "conventional" array such as :

```
int arr[2] = {4, 3};
```

If you create a pointer to this array :

```
int* foo = arr;
```

We make `foo` point to the first element of this array. `foo` has no idea if it's pointing to a "single variable" or to an array, it doesn't care. It's up to the programmer to know this information.

In your case the constructor assigns `m_pParticles` to point to the first element of the newly allocated array, all the pointer knows is that it's pointing to *some* `m_pParticles` object. The progammer knows that it's pointing to an array which makes accessing the pointer through index notation valid e.g `m_pParticles[5]`.

Comment: "_foo has no idea if it's pointing to a "single variable" or to an array_". ``T* foo`` always point to a single element. This element may be an element of an array or a "simple" (not from an array) element but it's always a single element. ``T (*foo)[N]`` is a pointer to an array.

Comment: @nefas You misunderstood what I was trying to tell OP. I meant that the pointer has no idea if where it's pointing to is a variable or a single element inside an array. I suppose my wording was off.

Comment: I understood what you meant but your wording is confusing: in your example ``foo` will never point to an array. TBH I often say that ``foo`` point to an array because it's simpler to say but with beginner it's important IMHO to be rigorous. That's why I'm nitpicking.

Answer (score 3):

There is no array of pointers to objects in the code you have shown.

`Particle* m_pParticles` is a pointer to `Particle`.  In C and C++ (and in general, in languages that support pointers) a plain pointer makes no distinction between pointing to a single item and pointing to the first item of an array of items, or even to an item somewhere in the middle of an array of items.

So, `Particle* m_pParticles`, which is a pointer to `Particle`, could be pointing either to a single `Particle`, or to an array of `Particle`.

The statement `m_pParticles = new Particle[NPARTICLES];` allocates an array of `Particle` containing `NPARTICLES` instances of `Particle` and sets `m_pParticles` to point to the first element of the array.

Comment: You might find it very useful: https://cdecl.org/ it translates C expressions to english.  (Sort of.)